# Traverse the following axis in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

This is a DOM fragment.

```
<p class="target">1</ p>
<p class="click"></ p>
<table>
<tr><td><p class="click"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<p class="target">2</p>
```

I would like to find the next p with the `target` class, it doesn't matter on what DOM level the p pressed with the`click` class is. In the case p with value 2

Something like

```
$ ("p.click").click(function () {
target = $(this).following("p.target").first()
});
```

But I can not find how to traverse the following axis in the DOM, except, maybe,  xpath which does not work in all browsers.

It would be great if I don't know something :)

**EDIT**

I was not correct enough writing the question. More suitable code is below. After pressing `click` I want to get the first `error` after

```
<input class="click" type="button" value="1">
<p class="error"></ p>
<table>
<tr><td><input class="click" type="button" value="2"></td></tr>
</table>
<p class="error"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By retrieving all `p`s initially, you can check the `.index` of the clicked element (`this`) in the collection. Then, access `index + 1` in that `p` collection:

```js
const $ps = $('p');
$("p.click").click(function() {
  const thisPIndex = $ps.index(this);
  console.log($($ps[thisPIndex + 1]).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="target">1</ p>
  <p class="click"></ p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="click">click</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="target">2</p>
```

If the clicked element is not necessarily one of the `<p>`s in the collection whose index you care about, you can follow a similar method by constructing a collection of *all* elements in the HTML, finding the index of the clicked element in the collection, constructing a new collection starting from that `index + 1`, `filter`ing by `p`, and checking the first matching element:

```js
const $ps = $('p');
const allElms = $('*');
$(".click").click(function() {
  const thisElmIndex = allElms.index(this);
  const followingElements = allElms.slice(thisElmIndex + 1);
  console.log(followingElements.filter('p')[0].textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="click" type="button" value="1">
<p class="error">1</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="click" type="button" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="error">2</p>
```

Comment: Beautiful approach!  +1 . But what if `click` and `target` are diff elements - f.e. button and p ?

Comment: If the clicked element is not a `<p>`, then how would you determine which `<p>` it's associated with? What's the sort of logic you're looking for? If it's a descendant, you could use `.querySelector`, if it's an ancestor, you can use `.closest`

Comment: Realy now it's a big form in which inputs  are placed in tables, divs and so on. But after any element or group of elements p.error is placed to show result. They  in most case are next after input, but some time not

Comment: Without seeing the HTML and knowing the desired behavior, it's hard to say

Comment: See edit, you can make a collection for *all* elements in the HTML, then check the clicked element's index in that big collection

Comment: You have `[0],value`, passing `value` as a second parameter. Did you mean `[0].textContent`? https://jsfiddle.net/mwLs87p1/ (period instead of `,`)

Comment: To reduce the size of the collection, in the case `const $ps = $('p.error');
const allElms = $('.click, p.error');` seems to be better

Comment: Yep, if you can count on the elements that you want to trigger the listener always being `input`s

Comment: I'v changed selector already `$('.click, p.error');` - https://jsfiddle.net/ce0g4xhj/

Answer (score 1):

## [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) & [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Assuming that there's an `.error` for each `.click`, we can:

- listen for a click on any `.click`
- find the clicked `.click` index number relating to all `.click` on the document
- then use that index number to find the equivalent index number among the `.error` on the document.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
/*
- Register click event on document
  - Any .click clicked will be $(this)
- Get the index number of the clicked button in relation to
  all .click on the document.
- Use the same index number to find the associated .error
*/
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(e) {
  var idx = $(this).index('.click');
  $('.error').eq(idx).show();
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input class="click" type="button" value="1">
<p class="error">ERROR 1</ p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="click" type="button" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="error">ERROR 2</p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Although it simplifies the code, but in a real task, there may be some clicks for one error. +1 in any way

Comment: Yeah, this is assuming it's one for one. If there is more than one `.click` for a single `.error` then a simple system of matching `data-*` attribute values would work well.

Comment: I never thought about DOM as ordered array of elements. Due to the answers, I've used such approach and find the quick solution. Thank to all, once more

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ("p.click").click(function () {
target = $(this).nextAll("p.target").first() // following-->nextAll
});
```

[Here is your playground](https://jsfiddle.net/kozmpe56/)